# Multuple Files upload error

Tags: file-upload

I am Using Multiple File Upload Code

```
if(isset($_FILES['imagaes']))
{
echo count($_FILES['imagaes']);die();
foreach($_FILES['imagaes']['name'] as $key=>$value)
{
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagaes']['tmp_name'][$key]) && $_FILES['imagaes']['error'][$key] == 0)
{
 My code is here--------
}
}
}
```

it is fit for upload
but when i use it for edit in same file (same html file field)
it gives me error of no name and if i count `$_FILES['imagaes']` array it returns `5` even i am not uploaded any file.
can anyone tell me plz..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line from your code

`echo count($_FILES['imagaes']);die();`

Your code will work fine